# Are both of these sentence correct? Why or why not?

Tags: conjunctions, clauses

These Sentences Are Tips On How To Do A Handstand. Are they both correct?

Tip: Kick too hard, and you'll flip over; kick too softly and you'll barely do a handstand at all.

Tip: Kick too hard, and you'll flip over; not hard enough, you won't get all the way up.

Comment: This may have been closed officially as "opinion-based", but I think it might have also been closed as a "proofreading request." ELL does not accept proofreading questions **unless a source of concern is clearly specified.** In other word, if you are concerned about the usage of "too softly" and "not hard enough," then **say so**, and the question can be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

The first one. There's no ambiguity over the options or what "not hard enough" might mean, it spells out the two extremes much more clearly.